# Closing a real question as duplicate of a Code Golf problem?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811922/) on SO. It is a serious question but it was closed as duplicate of a code-golf problem.

That doesn't seem fair or useful, I thought the main reason to mark a question as a duplicate was that it is likely to gain the same kind of answers.

This question asks for a sensible solution, and in a specific language (C#). If SO wants to be the repository for all programming questions then deferring to a page full of mutilated (saving on whitespace and identifier names is essential) solutions just isn't helpful. A link to it would have been useful of course.

Can we have some sort of guideline or verdict on this?

PS: I noticed that way down on the golf page there are a few usable answers. But they are hard to find for someone who drops in via Google.

Comment: The question is poorly written, I'm not surprised it was closed even if it weren't a duplicate.

Comment: It wasn't the best prose but it was clear what the asker wanted. Do you really close questions for bad style?

Comment: @Henk: actually, it's a bit unclear if he wants the number converted to words *completely*, or if the LSD should remain a number (as illustrated in his title). Personally, I think it's safe to assume he just didn't think through the problem particularly well / at all and merge it with previously-asked questions...
(there was another inconsistency in the question itself, as noted in the first comment, but that's been edited out now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, I reopened it.

Code Golf does imply shortest-possible solutions which aren't always what you want in a work environment -- that is, for a "real question".

Comment: FWIW, there are at least two previous instances of this question, (both of which also contain references to the Code Golf question, in addition to real answers) - so it's still a duplicate. See: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466042/convert-an-integer-to-a-string-of-words
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759198/how-to-convert-a-number-to-word-form-eg-72-to-seventy-two

Comment: Shog9, I think closing as duplicate of one of those would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

I agree.  Solving a code golf challenge is very different from writing readable, maintainable real-world code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the questions in question, I don't see where the two questions were that different. This particular code golf question didn't ask for "mutilated" code, and some of the people who would do such a thing have been noted to do it in real answers as well... so, same question, same answers.

Comment: Code Golf *inherently* asks for mutilated code by challenging people to come up with the shortest possible code, measured in bytes.

Comment: Except that was not one of the parameters specified in that particular question - usually if that is the goal it is specified.

Comment: Golf is a game in which the lowest score wins.  Thus "Code Golf" implies a shortest-is-best approach, whether specified or not.  If you *don't* want a shortest-is-best game, either don't call it "Code Golf", or explicitly state so in the goals.